# Will Linux servers running MONGODB be affected by plans to add a leap second in 2016?

Tags: linux, mongodb

I have read that there are plans to add a leap second in December 2016.
At work we are running a number of mongodb servers with ntpd installed to keep the time in sync and correct across them.

Does anybody know how this time change will affect us, i.e. whether or not we need to do anything other than ensure the normal operation of mongodb?

I can find no information on the sites for mongodb

For context:
red hat enterprise linux 6.6
mongodb3.2.3

Comment: See https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-and-leap-seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can operate normally as your Red Hat relies on NTP:

From [MongoDB and Leap Seconds](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-and-leap-seconds):

> Remember, MongoDB relies on host operating system capabilities for reading the wall clock time, and for synchronizing events with wall clock time. As such, you should ensure that the operating system running under MongoDB is itself prepared for leap seconds.

From [Resolve Leap Second Issues in Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://access.redhat.com/articles/15145):

> Systems running any version of Red Hat Enterprise Linux should automatically account for leap second corrections if they are using the NTP (Network Time Protocol) daemon to synchronize their local timekeeping with an NTP server. During the last day before a leap second correction, NTP servers should notify their clients that a leap second will occur, and at 23:59:59 UTC, the Linux kernel should add or remove an extra second by making the 60th second occur twice or removing it entirely.